# I don't understand how knockout.js mapping or components work at all?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've been (trying) to use Knockout.js mapping and components for the past few weeks and frankly, it just sucks. I swear I'm missing some magic piece that makes everything work nicely, because at the moment everything I'm trying to produce with it feels very disjointed and messy, and as a result, is mostly non-functional.

I have read the documentation through and though with little to no satisfaction or help.

## Use case

I have a main view model, but it's not the star of this story. It's the reusable component that I'm trying to build. Let's call it `TweetViewModel`. This component, depending on whether `params.action` is set to "create" or "show", will either allow a user to enter information about a tweet, or have it displayed to them:

#### Component View Model

```
define(['knockout','ko.mapping', 'jquery', 'text!components/tweet/tweet.html'], function(ko, koMapping, $, htmlString) {
    function TweetViewModel(params) {

        var self = this;

        self.tweet = params.tweet;
        self.action = params.action;

        self.tweetUrl = ko.observable();
        self.tweetUrl.subscribe(function(value) {
            var valueOfTwitterUrlField = value;

            // Check that the entered URL contains 'twitter' before sending a request (perform more thorough validation serverside)
            if (valueOfTwitterUrlField.indexOf('twitter.com') !== -1) {

                var explodedVals = valueOfTwitterUrlField.split('/');
                var id = explodedVals[explodedVals.length - 1];

                $.ajax('/myproj/create/retrievetweet/' + id, {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (response) {
                    }
                });
            }
            // Allow default action
            return true;
        });
    }

    return { viewModel: TweetViewModel, template: htmlString };
});
```

#### Template

```
<!-- ko if: action == 'show' -->
<div class="card twitter-card">

</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: action == 'create' -->
<div class="card twitter-card create">
    <label>Tweet URL</label>
    <input type="url" name="tweet_url" id="tweet_url" data-bind="textInput: tweetUrl" />
    <hr/>
    <p>Alternatively, if the tweet is no longer available, enter the tweet information below</p>
    <div class="tweeter-details">
        <img src="" />
        <span class="tweeter-screen-name" data-bind="text: tweet.tweet_user_screen_name"></span>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="tweeter-name" data-bind="value: tweet.tweet_user_name" />
    </div>
    <textarea class="tweet-text" data-bind="text: tweet.tweet_text"></textarea>
    <div class="date-input">
        <datetime params="value: tweet.tweet_created_at, type: 'datetime'"></datetime>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="tweet-images-list" data-bind="template: { name: 'tweet-images-template', foreach: tweet.images }">
</ul>
<div class="tweet-images-details"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/html" id="tweet-images-template">

</script>
```

This template is called via the following HTML:

```
<tweet params="action: 'create', tweet: tweetData"></tweet>
```

Where `action` is what portion of the template I am interested in showing and `tweet: tweetData` is how I want my parent viewmodel to communicate with my component. `tweetData` will likely be an object with the following properties:

```
self.tweet = {
    tweet_id: ko.observable(),
    tweet_text: ko.observable(),
    tweet_user_name: ko.observable(),
    tweet_user_screen_name: ko.observable(),
    tweet_created_at: ko.observable(),
    tweet_parent_id: ko.observable(),
    images: ko.observableArray()
}
```

At the moment, I am mainly concerned with displaying the "create" side of things. Simply displaying tweet data is very simple. Specifically, I want to know how my inputs/outputs on my component should work.

#### Questions

1) **If I'm passing through some JSON/JS object/dataset through from my parentviewmodel to my component, why the hell do I need to redefine the observable in my component?**

I mean this:

```
self.tweet = params.tweet;
```

Why is this necessary? If I don't do this, and try to refer to `tweet.tweet_user_name` on my template (or `params.tweet.tweet_user_name`) I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: tweet is not defined
```

Why is my template not aware of variables that are passed into the component constructor? Recall that my constructor is defined like so:

```
function TweetViewModel(params) {  //SNIP
```

If I do have to redefine my object on my component, will the changes made on it be mapped back to `tweetData` on the parentviewmodel?

2) **When I have multiple input and multiple output sources, how can I keep them all aligned with knockout mapping without it throwing a fit about undefined properties and not observing changes?**

If you take a look at my component, you can see I have two input sources for tweet information. One is the data coming through from `params`, the other is the AJAX request I make to my server to fetch data from the Twitter API.

These data sources look entirely different. Ideally, I want my "model" to look as if I have defined it above, a 'tweet' object with 7 observable properties ranging from `images` to `tweet_id`. The data coming from `tweetData` on my parentviewmodel should look something like this, but it may be empty when I'm expecting a tweet to be created. The data coming from my AJAX request will be a raw response from the twitter API that I need to format.

Specifically, I have the following situations and problems:

- **I cannot guarantee that `tweetData` will always contain information or an outline of my preferred model.**

This usually happens when a tweet is being created outright and doesn't exist apart from the observable object on my parentviewmodel. The variable I pass to my component is something I *expect* to be filled by Knockout mapping on my component - I shouldn't need to pass in a empty object with all the properties already formatted.

- **When I come to overwrite my `params.tweet` value with the data I recieved back from an AJAX request, it won't actually overwrite the values in `self.tweet`, and it doesn't update my data bindings**.

Consider this code:

```
self.tweet.tweet_text = ko.observable("foo")

$.ajax('/myproj/create/retrievetweet/' + id, {
dataType: 'json',
type: 'GET',
success: function (response) {
    self.tweet = {
        tweet_id: ko.observable(response.id),
        tweet_text: ko.observable(response.text),
        tweet_user_name: ko.observable(response.user.name),
        tweet_user_screen_name: ko.observable(response.user.screen_name),
        tweet_created_at: ko.observable(response.created_at),
        tweet_parent_id: ko.observable(response.in_reply_to_status_id),
        images: ko.observableArray(response.entities.media)
    }
}
});
```

This success callback won't actually set anything for some reason on my template. My text binding which is bound to `tweet.tweet_text` will still show "foo", even after I have received a response that is valid and should reset it as I have defined above.

Using knockout mapping with the response from the server is even more disgusting. There is no way to whitelist properties I want to observe, I can only blacklist via the `ignore` options setting - considering how much data Twitter returns, that's a lot of properties to manually ignore! Also, the property names that Twitter returns don't match the property names I'm trying to use (see above), so I'm not even sure knockout mapping is a good fit here.

3) **How have I been using Knockout.js + mapping + components incorrectly, and what would be a good starting structure for the component that I'm trying to create?**

I'm at my wits end here, and I'll happily try any and all suggestions thrown at me. Ideally, I'd like as many of my questions answered as possible.

Comment: If you can't be remotely constructive, go away.

Comment: all i am trying to say is if you can make it short you get more answers . being rude gets you no where . mind your manners . Good luck

Comment: No, that's not what you tried to say at all. You said "to broad to look & even try to answer". There's no constructive criticism there whatsoever and fundamentally it contributes nothing. 

Now you've wasted both my time and your own time with this pointless little conversation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Components have their own viewmodels because by design they are reusable and could be used across different apps with different viewmodels. If you want to reference the main viewmodel, pass it as a parameter.
2. Don't re-assign bound observables or variables that contain bound observables. You can set their values using the normal function call (e.g. `self.tweet.tweet_id(newValue)`), but if you use an equals sign, you're generally throwing the bound variable away.
3. If you want to whitelist values, you might as well create and assign the variables, I think. `ko.mapping` won't save you anything.

Comment: Frankly, it doesn't sound like ko.mapping or knockout is very useful then. I might as well give Angular a go at this point.